# How to compile Bluez btmgmt on Ubuntu Core?

Tags: ubuntu-core, bluez

I'm moving a script from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu Core 16. In the process I am also moving from Bluez 5.37 to the version provided with the Bluez snap, 5.44-2.

In the Bluez snap, the `btmgmt` tool is not precompiled. I had been utilizing its ability to be scripted with commands like

```
rm -rf /var/lib/bluetooth/* >/dev/null 2>&1
btmgmt --index $hci ltks >/dev/null 2>&1
btmgmt --index $hci power off >/dev/null 2>&1
btmgmt --index $hci power on >/dev/null 2>&1
btmgmt --index $hci le on >/dev/null 2>&1
```

where $hci is the btle interface.

Is there a current script-able alternative that I haven't found from scouring the man pages of the Bluez tools I have access to, or should I try to compile the `btmgmt` tool, and if so, how?

### Progress Update 1:

I have began playing with the classic snap, intended for use with development of new snaps and explained in the [Build your own snap tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/create-first-snap?_ga=2.254458122.30178948.1497382838-1654206005.1497382838#1). It allowed for me to apt-get install bluez, which included the btmgmt tool. My problem now is that I am unable to power cycle hci0 without rebooting the entire box, defeating the point of the script. Also, when it is on, I am still unable to pair successfully to my desired bt device.

### Progress Update 2:

With the `sudo snap revert bluez` command I was able to roll back the native snap to 5.37, but I am still unable to locate btmgmt, or the source code to compile it on the system.

Comment: My current research has located [this github issue page](https://github.com/chrippa/ds4drv/issues/123) that gives me hope that btmgmt is what I should be using, and that it is somewhere in the source. I just need to find where it is to compile. [This page](https://urbanjack.wordpress.com/2014/06/05/how-to-set-bluez-into-ble-or-le-only-mode-ibeacon/) is helpful except for the 'Go to where the source code is', as I have yet to locate where snaps place their source.